# Entity Framework creating null entry in the DB on POST

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I've got a simple form that creates Categories with a name and a List of Cars assigned to them.

Everything works fine minus the fact that for each entry in the DB I get a second one before that is null everywhere except for the parent BrandId.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddNewCategory(AddNewCategoryPostViewModel categoryInfo)
{
    var brand = _repository.GetBrandById(categoryInfo.BrandId);
    if (categoryInfo.Name == null || categoryInfo.Cars == null)
    {
        if (categoryInfo.Name == null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Name", "The name cannot be empty.");
        }

        if (categoryInfo.Cars == null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Cars", "At least one car must be selected.");
        }

        var cars = _insplib.GetDevCategorysForProject((int)brand.Id);

        ViewBag.Cars = cars;
        ViewBag.Selectedcars = categoryInfo.Cars;

        return View(new Category()
                        {
                            Brand = brand
                        });
    }

    var category = new Category()
                        {
                            DateEntered = DateTime.Now,
                            IsArchived = false,
                            Name = categoryInfo.Name,
                            BrandId = categoryInfo.BrandId
                        };

    _repository.AddOrUpdateCategory(category);

    // more code here added to add the cars, but not relevant to this issue.

    return RedirectToRoute("Category", new { brand = category.Brand.ShortName, categoryId = category.Id });
}
```

My repository method is:

```
public Category AddOrUpdateCategory(Category category)
{
    if (category.Id == 0)
        _context.AddToCategorys(category);

    _context.SaveChanges();

    return category;
}
```

As you can see it's a pretty straight forward POST, yet every time I create a Category, I get two entries:

```
ID  Name    DateEntered IsArchived  
5   NULL    NULL    NULL    4
6   NewCategory 10/6/2011   False   4
```

My trick has been to simply go through the table and remove any Category that has null values in Name. But that's obviously not resolving the actual issue.

Comment: Does your matching GET also `return View(new Category{});` I would say this is the record that is being saved. You could test my theory by setting one of the other properties and see if it shows up in the blank record.

Comment: May be you are calling your `Post` method twice. Did you check it with a break point ?

Comment: @Jayantha, yes that's already checked and it's not happening.

Comment: @ChrisSainty, you're right! That's my problem. I'm not passing a new Category and instead using a ViewBag to pass just the Brand object I need for the title and Id on my page! Thanks!  Put your solution as an answer and I'll mark it as such :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments, It is actually your GET that will be creating the blank record when it passes a `new Category()` to the view.
 Some of the ORM's detect new'd up objects and add them to your context for you. Which helpfully creates confusing issues like this one.